# Bluetooth discovery/monitoring in python 3.x on windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, bluetooth, windows-10

Python 3.7

Windows 10 64 bit.

---

Research shows solutions on Mac/Linux, or WinXP in 2.7, but cannot find a viable solution in 3.x on Windows 10.

---

More specifically, my goal is to setup real-time monitoring of the following value:
[image: screenshot of bluetooth capture]